# Problems with TransactionScope in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

I've build a class to synchronize data between two different datasources. This synchronization is divided into multiple parts (and methods). Every method has his own TransactionScope and the methods are run sequentially.

Everytime I Run this code I get the following errormessage:

**"The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed. The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements."**

The following code is an example of such a method with a TransactionScope:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
        try
        {
            using (var _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
            {
                using (SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {
                    _connection.Open();

                    DoSomething()...
                }

                _transactionScope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (TransactionAbortedException e)
        {
            nlog.Error(string.Format("The transaction has been aborted: {0}", e.Message));
            throw e;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
}
```

It seems that the call **"_transactionScope.Complete()"** isn't enough to kill the transactionscope.. Does anyone have a clue what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Thanks for your replies. After a few tests I discovered that this problem only exists when there are multiple queries in one method. for example:

```
 try
    {
        using (TransactionScope _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
        {
            using (SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                _connection.Open();

                //new method:
                using (TransactionScope _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
                {
                    //a selectquery
                }

                //an update or insert query

            _transactionScope.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your transaction lasting more than 10 minutes?

Comment: There are some transactions I think that last more then 10 minutes, but I handled that by setting the 'transactionOptions.Timeout' property and de SqlCommand.CommandTimeout property to one hour.

Comment: This error can occur if the transaction runs for a longer period than the maxTimeout. See this blogpost: http://thecodesaysitall.blogspot.se/2012/04/long-running-systemtransactions.html or this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10017056/205023

Comment: Just a technical note... don't "throw e", use just "throw". This preserves the call stack.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the constructor.

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                new TransactionOptions()
                { 
                    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable,
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)
                }))
```

Answer (score 3):

I did a method for creating a Max Timeout value on a transaction scope

```
public static TransactionScope CreateDefaultTransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption option = TransactionScopeOption.Required)
    {
        var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
        transactionOptions.Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
        return new TransactionScope(option, transactionOptions);
    }
```

and then you would use it:

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = TransactionHelper.CreateDefaultTransactionScope())
```

Comment: Check out this link as well:   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/250b40b9-0838-4142-a8ff-d9d26690083b/