# Unclear exception from TransactionScope

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, ado.net, transactionscope

I use TransactionScrope in my code to execute 50 SQL command on SQL Server 2008 R2.
this is an example for my code:

```
   private void DoSomething()
    {
        bool IsComplete = false;
        SqlCommand sqlComm = null;
        //6 hours!!!
        TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0);
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope t = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, ts1))
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
                {
                    //open sql connection
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        //create new sqlCommand
                        sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
                        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
                        {
                            IsComplete = true;
                            //This command takes 15 minutes
                            sqlComm.CommandText = "exec TestSp";
                            sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn;
                            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            sqlComm.CommandTimeout = 18000;
                            //Executing my command
                            int j = sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            sw.WriteLine("Finsh Executing SQL Command:" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                            sw.Flush();
                        }
                        //End
                        IsComplete = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        IsComplete = false;
                        string Message = ex.Message;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (sqlComm != null)
                            sqlComm.Dispose();
                        if (IsComplete)
                            t.Complete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string messagee = ex.Message;
            //do something
        }
        finally
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Finsh");
        }
    }
```

When the procedure takes more than 10 minutes I get this exception:

> The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.

I tired a lot of options by changing the TimeSpam and changing the SqlCommand.Timout but for some reason i get this exception. The exception occur after the first execution that takes a lot of time. For example if i have 100 stored procedure and text command and all the command takes less than 5 minutes and only one command takes more than 10 minutes the execution of the next command after the long command will cause the exception to occur.

Does anybody get any idea for the cause?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A 6 hour transaction is quote honestly crazy. VERY bad voodoo. Transactions should be *very* brief. I don't imagine this is helping. I would redesign this...

Answer (score 3):

I think the thing to try here is simply to move the transaction complete *outside* the connection, i.e.

```
using(var tran = ...)
{
    bool isComplete;
    using(var conn = ...)
    {
         //...
    }

    if(isComplete)
        tran.Complete();
}
```

Also note that *most* times, it is easier to simply let exception handling bypass the Complete() for us, i.e.

```
using(var tran = ...)
{
    using(var conn = ...)
    {
        //...
    }

    // if we get an exception, we won't get here
    tran.Complete();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but still not work... After 10 minutes the next sqlCommand return the same exception. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user436862 my *main* idea here is that this work is simply too big to be in a transaction... 10 minutes? 6 hours? most transactions last (at most) *seconds*

Comment: I get a transaction of conversion tables of int to bigint. I create empty table and copy all the records from 4 tables that bind by the int key (in the new tables by bigint key) so i need to insert all the data from the old tables to the new one by one transaction. because i have millions of records this transaction takes more than 15 minutes...

Answer (score 3):

This error can occur when the transaction runs for a longer period than the `maxTimeout` for `System.Transactions`. The default value for `maxTimeout` is 10 minutes.

You can read more about it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10017056/205023 or in this blog post: http://thecodesaysitall.blogspot.se/2012/04/long-running-systemtransactions.html

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the transaction is just timing out seeing it it fails after a set amount of time.