# C# controlling a transaction across multiple databases

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

Say I'm having a Windows Form application which connected to *`n`* databases, with *`n`* connections opened simultaneously.

What I'm looking for is to do a transaction with all of those databases in one go.

For example if I were to have 2 database connections :

```
using (ITransaction tx1 = session1.OpenTransaction())
{
    using (ITransaction tx2 = session2.OpenTransaction())
    {
        // Do the query thingy here
    }
}
```

Writing all that is fine at first, but things get kind of redundant when I wanted to query here and there, and not to mention the possibility to adding a new connection.

What I wanted is to loop all of the registered session and wrap it up in a service, probably something like this :

```
class TransactionManager
{
    private ISession[] _sessions;

    public TransactionManager(string[] connectionStrings)
    {
        // Initialize the sessions here
    }

    public function DoTransaction(string query)
    {
        foreach (ISession session in _sessions)
        {
            // What to do here? Using? Try-catch?
        }
    }
}
```

If I were to use using in the `foreach` loop, it would mean that if connection A successful but connection B wasn't, then only connection B would be rolled back.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It seems you may be re-inventing [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx). Doing all this under a unit of work is straightforward*:

```
  using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
  {
     ... Do Stuff with Connection 1 using SqlDataReader
     ... Do Stuff with Connection 2 using Entity Framework
     ... Do Stuff with Connection 3 on another Oracle Database
     ... And for good measure do some stuff in MSMQ or other DTC resource
     scope.Complete(); // If you are happy
  }
```

`Stuff` doesn't need to be inline at all - it can be in a different class, or a different assembly. There's no need to explicitly register database or queue connections with the `TransactionScope` - everything happens `automagically`, provided that the resources you use are able to [enlist into an ambient transaction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896149%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Now the small print:

- `*` Any time you use more than one database connection concurrently, or different connection strings, or multiple technologies, this will require [2 phase commit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) and escalate to a Distributed transaction in order to ensure ACID across the resources. MSDTC itself has lots more small print and poses many more [challenges in a corporate network](https://web.archive.org/web/20150224012725/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2011/11/22/troubleshooting-msdtc-communication-checklist.aspx), like [firewalls](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/250367), [clustering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd897479.aspx), [security configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731495.aspx) and [bugs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqltechnet/2012/08/06/blocking-in-sql-server-by-spid-2-orphan-distributed-transactions/).
- However, with Lightweight transactions on MS Sql Server, if you can keep all your connections using the same database and same
  connection string settings, and close each connection before opening
  the next, then you [can avoid
  DTC](http://petermeinl.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/avoiding-unwanted-escalation-to-distributed-transactions/).
- Distributed Transactions are complex - you will need to install and configure the MSDTC service on your app server, and all distributed resources will need to have MSDTC or equivalent (e.g. [XA, LUA](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/how-it-works-sql-server-dtc-msdtc-and-xa-transactions/ba-p/3204504)) configured.
- MSDTC isn't yet fully supported on [.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#distributed-transactions)
- Maintaining a transaction across multiple ACID resources will invariably maintain locks on these resources, until the transaction is committed or rolled back. This often doesn't make for good neighbourliness in a high volume enterprise, so be sure to consider the consequences of the locking.
- If the `Stuff` is done across multiple threads, you'll need to rope in [DependentTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.dependenttransaction.aspx)
- A last point worth mentioning is the default isolation level with `TransactionScope` is Serializable, which is prone to deadlocks. In most non-critical scenarios you'll probably be able drop this down to [Read Committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292763/why-is-system-transactions-transactionscope-default-isolationlevel-serializable).

Comment: Can't believe I just know about TransactionScope just now. Where have I been all this time??

Comment: Also, the `TransactionScope` has a terrible habit of escalating multiple connections to the MSDTC, which has terrible performance. Be weary of it.

Comment: Does your `*` bullet point apply to the given example as well, i.e. multiple database connections *of completely different types*?

Comment: Yes. e.g. provided that all databases are configured accordingly, you will be able to conduct a 2 phase transaction across SqlServer, Oracle and an MQSeries queue. When communicating with non-Windows tech stack (e.g. to Oracle hosted on *nix server), you'll likely need to configure [XA](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342335.aspx) on your originating .Net server(s). However, you may want to analyse the negative effects of distributed locking before hurting your enterprise with ACID transactions. There are (admittedly complicated) alternatives like compensation and BASE.

Comment: Can I just confirm, is it possible to use 2 DbContexts, both connected to different DBs on different SQL Servers, within a single TransactionScope and all operations will be atomic?

Comment: Yes - provided both sql servers and your app server have DTC enabled. The price of atomicity is locking rows touched by the SaveChanges until the scope is committed.

Answer (score 7):

use TransactionScope, it will take care of committing or rolling back all included transactions:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
   ... // your old code

   ts.Complete()
}
```